# linker could not found object files from different directory with scons

Tags: compilation, linker, ld, scons

Currently, I make a project with scons.
I compiled source codes and it is time to link them.
However, I got an error that ld cannot find object files.

The SConscript is located in src/kernel32, and

```
import os, sys

# Compile CPP
env_gpp_options = {
    'CXX'         : 'x86_64-pc-linux-g++',
    'CXXFLAGS'    : '-std=c++11 -g -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti',
    'LINK'        : 'x86_64-pc-linux-ld',
    'LINKFLAGS'   : '-melf_i386 -T scripts/elf_i386.x -nostdlib -e main -Ttext 0x10200',
}
env_gpp = Environment(**env_gpp_options)
env_gpp.Append(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})

object_cpp_list = Glob('*.cpp')

for object_cpp in object_cpp_list:
    env_gpp.Object(object_cpp)

# Find all object file
object_target_list = Glob('*.o')

# Linking
env_link_target = 'kernel32.elf'

env_gpp.Program(env_link_target, object_target_list)
```

and message I got is

```
x86_64-pc-linux-g++ -o build/kernel32/cpu.o -c -std=c++11 -g -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti src/kernel32/cpu.cpp
x86_64-pc-linux-g++ -o build/kernel32/main.o -c -std=c++11 -g -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti src/kernel32/main.cpp
x86_64-pc-linux-g++ -o build/kernel32/memory.o -c -std=c++11 -g -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti src/kernel32/memory.cpp
x86_64-pc-linux-g++ -o build/kernel32/pageManager.o -c -std=c++11 -g -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti src/kernel32/pageManager.cpp
x86_64-pc-linux-g++ -o build/kernel32/utils.o -c -std=c++11 -g -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti src/kernel32/utils.cpp
x86_64-pc-linux-ld -o build/kernel32/kernel32.elf -melf_i386 -T scripts/elf_i386.x -nostdlib -e main -Ttext 0x10200 build/kernel32/asmUtils.o build/kernel32/cpu.o build/kernel32/main.o build/kernel32/memory.o build/kernel32/pageManager.o build/kernel32/utils.o
x86_64-pc-linux-ld: cannot find main.o
scons: *** [build/kernel32/kernel32.elf] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I checked the directory, build/kernel32/, and I found main.o file.
What is my mistake?
Is there an way to change working directory for scons?

Please let me know what I missed.

Comment: Does it work when you call the same command in the terminal/shell?

Comment: Yes, I did "x86_64-pc-linux-ld -o kernel32.elf -melf_i386 -T ../../elf_i386.x -nostdlib -e main -Ttext 0x10200 main.o cpu.o memory.o pageManager.o utils.o asmUtils.o" in "build/kernel32" directory, and it worked. I think there is a problem of working directory, but I do not know what it is exactly, and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you post enough of your SConstruct to make the SConscript work? (so we can see how you are using VariantDir and/or variant_dir)

Comment: Please try running the build command, as given in your first post, from the top-level folder...not from `build/kernel`. This is supposed to ensure that it's really an SCons problem, and not related to your compiler/linker. If the latter is true then you'll have to find out how the command (from top-level) should actually look. Then we can work on how to teach the new trick to SCons.

Comment: I did and got the same error. I did "x86_64-pc-linux-ld -o build/kernel32/kernel32.elf -melf_i386 -T scripts/elf_i386.x -nostdlib -e main -Ttext 0x10200 build/kernel32/asmUtils.o build/kernel32/cpu.o build/kernel32/main.o build/kernel32/memory.o build/kernel32/pageManager.o build/kernel32/utils.o" in top-level folder, and the error message is "x86_64-pc-linux-ld: cannot find main.o"

Comment: So it's not really a SCons problem in first place, you might want to make that clear by editing your question...or even removing the "scons" tag. Once you figure out what the correct syntax would be, porting it to SCons should be easy again.

Comment: Ok. I understood. This is not a functional problem of scons. I will ask again with more specific question. BTW, I could figure out what the problem is exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import os, sys

# Compile CPP
env_gpp_options = {
    'CXX'         : 'x86_64-pc-linux-g++',
    'CXXFLAGS'    : '-std=c++11 -g -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti',
    'LINK'        : 'x86_64-pc-linux-ld',
    'LINKFLAGS'   : '-melf_i386 -T scripts/elf_i386.x -nostdlib -e main -Ttext 0x10200',
}
env_gpp = Environment(**env_gpp_options)
env_gpp.Append(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})

object_cpp_list = Glob('*.cpp')

object_target_list = []
for object_cpp in object_cpp_list:
    object_target_list.extend(env_gpp.Object(object_cpp))

# Linking
env_link_target = 'kernel32.elf'

env_gpp.Program(env_link_target, object_target_list)
```

Or

```
import os, sys

# Compile CPP
env_gpp_options = {
    'CXX'         : 'x86_64-pc-linux-g++',
    'CXXFLAGS'    : '-std=c++11 -g -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti',
    'LINK'        : 'x86_64-pc-linux-ld',
    'LINKFLAGS'   : '-melf_i386 -T scripts/elf_i386.x -nostdlib -e main -Ttext 0x10200',
}
env_gpp = Environment(**env_gpp_options)
env_gpp.Append(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})

object_cpp_list = Glob('*.cpp')

# Linking
env_link_target = 'kernel32.elf'

env_gpp.Program(env_link_target, object_cpp_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, they are not work for me. I tried your first answer, but the message is the same before.

Comment: Actually, the code hich I wrote above is not complete. There are more source files of assembly. Therefore, I could not use env_gpp.Program() directory.

Comment: In that case include the assembly files as well in the source list to Program and SCons should do the correct thing and compile those to objects and then link against them, just as it does with cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

This is full scons scripts.

In project root directory,

```
#SConstruct

build_dir = 'build'

# Build
SConscript(['src/SConscript'], variant_dir = build_dir, duplicate = 0)

# Clean
Clean('.', build_dir)
```

In src directory

```
#SConscript for src
SConscript(['bootloader/SConscript',
        'kernel32/SConscript'])
```

In kernel32 directory

```
#SConscript for kernel32
import os, sys

# Build entry
env_entry = Environment(tools=['default', 'nasm'])

target_entry = 'entry.bin'

object_entry = 'entry.s'

output_entry = env_entry.Object(target_entry, object_entry)

# Compile CPP
env_gpp_options = {
    'CXX'       : 'x86_64-pc-linux-g++',
    'CXXFLAGS'  : '-std=c++11 -g -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti',
    'LINK'        : 'x86_64-pc-linux-ld',
    'LINKFLAGS'   : '-melf_i386 -T scripts/elf_i386.x -nostdlib -e main -Ttext 0x10200',
}
env_gpp = Environment(**env_gpp_options)
env_gpp.Append(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})

object_cpp_list = Glob('*.cpp')

for object_cpp in object_cpp_list:
    env_gpp.Object(object_cpp)

# Compile ASM
env_nasm = Environment(tools=['default', 'nasm'])
env_nasm.Append(ASFLAGS='-f elf32')

object_nasm_list = Glob('*.asm')

for object_nasm in object_nasm_list:
    env_nasm.Object(object_nasm)

# Find all object file
object_target_list = Glob('*.o')
object_target_list.append('entry.bin')

# Linking
env_link_target = 'kernel32.elf'

env_gpp.Program(env_link_target, object_target_list)
```

Thank you for your attention.