# How to change working directory in scons

Tags: directory, makefile, ld, scons

I have a project built with *make*, but I want to shift to *scons*.

However, I could not link object files in scons, so I want to know how to change working directory in *scons*.

What I exactly want is

```
make -C $(OBJECTDIRECTORY) -f $(SOURCEDIRECTORY)./Makefile InternalDependency
```

This is one line from my Makefile, and works well.

However, when scons builds my project, it does

```
x86_64-pc-linux-ld -o build/kernel32/kernel32.elf -melf_i386 -T scripts/elf_i386.x -nostdlib -e main -Ttext 0x10200 build/kernel32/asmUtils.o build/kernel32/cpu.o build/kernel32/main.o build/kernel32/memory.o build/kernel32/pageManager.o build/kernel32/utils.o
```

and got an error,

```
x86_64-pc-linux-ld: cannot find main.o
```

. Even thouh I do same command in shell manually, I got the same error.

However, if I move to build/kernel32, and do manually

```
x86_64-pc-linux-ld -o kernel32.elf -melf_i386 -T ../../elf_i386.x -nostdlib -e main -Ttext 0x10200 main.o cpu.o memory.o pageManager.o utils.o asmUtils.o
```

and it works.

My assumption is ld could not link object files in some upper directory.

So, is there any way to do like "-C" option of Make?
Or any other workaround wayin scons?

Here is my *SConscript*, and *SConsctruct*.

In project root directory,

```
#SConstruct

build_dir = 'build'

# Build
SConscript(['src/SConscript'], variant_dir = build_dir, duplicate = 0)

# Clean
Clean('.', build_dir)
```

In src directory

```
#SConscript for src
SConscript(['bootloader/SConscript',
        'kernel32/SConscript'])
```

In kernel32 directory

```
#SConscript for kernel32
import os, sys

# Build entry
env_entry = Environment(tools=['default', 'nasm'])

target_entry = 'entry.bin'

object_entry = 'entry.s'

output_entry = env_entry.Object(target_entry, object_entry)

# Compile CPP
env_gpp_options = {
    'CXX'       : 'x86_64-pc-linux-g++',
    'CXXFLAGS'  : '-std=c++11 -g -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti',
    'LINK'        : 'x86_64-pc-linux-ld',
    'LINKFLAGS'   : '-melf_i386 -T scripts/elf_i386.x -nostdlib -e main -Ttext 0x10200',
}
env_gpp = Environment(**env_gpp_options)
env_gpp.Append(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})

object_cpp_list = Glob('*.cpp')

for object_cpp in object_cpp_list:
    env_gpp.Object(object_cpp)

# Compile ASM
env_nasm = Environment(tools=['default', 'nasm'])
env_nasm.Append(ASFLAGS='-f elf32')

object_nasm_list = Glob('*.asm')

for object_nasm in object_nasm_list:
    env_nasm.Object(object_nasm)

# Find all object file
object_target_list = Glob('*.o')
object_target_list.append('entry.bin')

# Linking
env_link_target = 'kernel32.elf'

env_gpp.Program(env_link_target, object_target_list)
```

Pleas let me know. Thank you.

The log for "--tree=prune" is

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
x86_64-pc-linux-ld -o build/kernel32/kernel32.elf -melf_i386 -T scripts/elf_i386.x -nostdlib -e main -Ttext 0x10200 build/kernel32/asmUtils.o build/kernel32/cpu.o build/kernel32/main.o build/kernel32/memory.o build/kernel32/pageManager.o build/kernel32/utils.o build/kernel32/entry.bin
+-.
  +-SConstruct
  +-build
  | +-src/SConscript
  | +-build/bootloader
  | | +-src/bootloader/BootLoader.asm
  | | +-src/bootloader/SConscript
  | | +-build/bootloader/bootloader.bin
  | |   +-src/bootloader/BootLoader.asm
  | |   +-/usr/bin/nasm
  | +-build/kernel32
  |   +-src/kernel32/SConscript
  |   +-src/kernel32/asmUtils.asm
  |   +-build/kernel32/asmUtils.o
  |   | +-src/kernel32/asmUtils.asm
  |   | +-/usr/bin/nasm
  |   +-src/kernel32/cpu.cpp
  |   +-build/kernel32/cpu.o
  |   | +-src/kernel32/cpu.cpp
  |   | +-src/kernel32/cpu.hpp
  |   | +-src/kernel32/types.hpp
  |   | +-/home/xaliver/BuildTools/cross/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-g++
  |   +-build/kernel32/entry.bin
  |   | +-src/kernel32/entry.s
  |   | +-/usr/bin/nasm
  |   +-src/kernel32/entry.s
  |   +-build/kernel32/kernel32.elf
  |   | +-[build/kernel32/asmUtils.o]
  |   | +-[build/kernel32/cpu.o]
  |   | +-build/kernel32/main.o
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/main.cpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/cpu.hpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/memory.hpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/types.hpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/utils.hpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/pageManager.hpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/page.hpp
  |   | | +-/home/xaliver/BuildTools/cross/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-g++
  |   | +-build/kernel32/memory.o
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/memory.cpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/memory.hpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/pageManager.hpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/page.hpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/types.hpp
  |   | | +-/home/xaliver/BuildTools/cross/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-g++
  |   | +-build/kernel32/pageManager.o
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/pageManager.cpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/pageManager.hpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/page.hpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/types.hpp
  |   | | +-/home/xaliver/BuildTools/cross/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-g++
  |   | +-build/kernel32/utils.o
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/utils.cpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/utils.hpp
  |   | | +-src/kernel32/types.hpp
  |   | | +-/home/xaliver/BuildTools/cross/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-g++
  |   | +-[build/kernel32/entry.bin]
  |   | +-/home/xaliver/BuildTools/cross/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-ld
  |   +-src/kernel32/main.cpp
  |   +-[build/kernel32/main.o]
  |   +-src/kernel32/memory.cpp
  |   +-[build/kernel32/memory.o]
  |   +-src/kernel32/pageManager.cpp
  |   +-[build/kernel32/pageManager.o]
  |   +-src/kernel32/utils.cpp
  |   +-[build/kernel32/utils.o]
  +-src
    +-src/SConscript
    +-src/bootloader
    | +-src/bootloader/BootLoader.asm
    | +-src/bootloader/SConscript
    +-src/kernel32
      +-src/kernel32/SConscript
      +-src/kernel32/asmUtils.asm
      +-src/kernel32/cpu.cpp
      +-src/kernel32/cpu.hpp
      +-src/kernel32/entry.s
      +-src/kernel32/main.cpp
      +-src/kernel32/memory.cpp
      +-src/kernel32/memory.hpp
      +-src/kernel32/page.hpp
      +-src/kernel32/pageManager.cpp
      +-src/kernel32/pageManager.hpp
      +-src/kernel32/types.hpp
      +-src/kernel32/utils.cpp
      +-src/kernel32/utils.hpp
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: Isn't this the same issue you're having here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928921/linker-could-not-found-object-files-from-different-directory-with-scons

Comment: Post the output of :  strace -o logfile x86_64-pc-linux-ld -o build/kernel32/kernel32.elf -melf_i386 -T scripts/elf_i386.x -nostdlib -e main -Ttext 0x10200 build/kernel32/asmUtils.o build/kernel32/cpu.o build/kernel32/main.o build/kernel32/memory.o build/kernel32/pageManager.o build/kernel32/utils.o

Comment: Also post the output of : scons --tree=prune

Comment: Yes, thisi is the same issue with what you mention. I compared Makefile and SConscript, and I think I need the same functionality with "-C" option of make. So I changed my question about that.

Comment: @bdbaddog, I tried strace for my project, and I found there are two result. When I do that after clean, it does not create build directory. However, if I do "scons", then do strace, it create build directory and show same error. So I share both with dropbox. This is for only strace, https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzesgtpsvtlxn9r/Strace_log?dl=0, and this is scons and strace, https://www.dropbox.com/s/wyq16shyugd66s5/Scons_Strace_log?dl=0. Thank you again.

Comment: I attached the result of '--tree=prune' at the end of question.

Comment: You should then remove your old question if you're replacing it with this one..  Or I think you can change the title of your other question, though I'm not convinced that changing directories.

Comment: This still looks like a problem with your linker `ld` to me, and it's not really SCons-related. I'm particularly vexed that the linker tries to open `main.o`, instead of using the full path as specified. It's also suspicious that it opens `main.o` first, although other objects to link have been given before on the command line. My guess is that it has to do with the `-e` option for the start symbol. Can you try to rename `-e main` to `-e foo`, just to see whether then `foo.o` can't be found? That would explain a few things...and leave you with the task of fixing the command line first.

Comment: I tried -e main, but ld found main.o file, too. I also tried default ld, but it also found main.o. However, ld is executed in build/kernel32 directory, ld worked. So what I want to know is scons option like -C in make. If I use make -C build/kernel32 -f ../../src/kernel32/Makefile TAG, it works. Does scons have any API like that? I could not find it until now.

Comment: Please look at the scons manpage  SCons has -C and -f flags. http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html.  Which compilers are you using? (vendor/version/platform you're compiling on/for/where can they be downloaded)

Comment: I am using gcc compiler, but I manually configured it. I found the options, but I think they are for command line. I do not know how to write sconscript to do the same functionality of '-C' and '-f'. So, I asked API in my previous comment. If it is possible to use '-C' and '-f' in sconscript, could you let me know how to use it . I think I bother you guys with very simple question. I am sorry, but I am a complete newbie for scons. I can hold using make, but I think scons is good tool to build a project. Therefore, I have tried to know how to use it even though it takes my time a lot.

Comment: I tried os.chdir() and env.Command() with -C and -f or chdir option. However, ld still tries to find /build/kernel32/main.o. It does not move to the directory. I do not know why..

Comment: Check the [User Guide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html) in sect. 14.2 "Path names are relative to the SConscript directory": [...] Second, unlike standard recursive use of Make, SCons stays in the top-level directory [...]